# What is the ABAP command to abort?

Tags: abap, abort

I would like to know if there's an ABAP command which will mimic exit 1(in shell scripting), which will abort?

Answer (score 5):

[STOP](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/Helpdata/en/9f/db9ae435c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm), [RETURN](http://help-legacy.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abenexit_procedure_guidl.htm) or [EXIT](https://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/9f/db9af135c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) depending on the scenario.

PS. links go to relevant SAP help.

Comment: I think it depends on the case, but in module type programs you can have problems with exiting by using these commands. You have to end screen performing, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to end silently a program, check @Gert Beukema's answer. If the exit's cause is an error, to instantly abort a program can be achieved by giving a message with type 'A' or 'X' (or E if it's in a right place).

`'A' is for Abort:` It provides information about processing errors but the processing cannot be resumed.

`'X' is for Exit:` It provides no processing information, but rather, a stack dump for the state of the system.

More information can be found on [this](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ABAP+Message+Error+Handling+Standards) page